# Propel returns different output for the same query with same table

Tags: php, propel

I have propel query

```
$articles = ArticlesQuery::create()->find();
var_dump($articles);
exit;
```

which queries the article table (id, users_id, article_category_id, images_id, title, body, approved, created_date, deleted) but the result I get is very different.

expected result is

```
object(PropelObjectCollection)[34]

object(Articles)[35]
  protected 'startCopy' => boolean false
  protected 'id' => int 1
  protected 'users_id' => int 1
  protected 'articles_category_id' => int 1
  protected 'images_id' => int 1
  protected 'title' => string 'Article Title Here updated' (length=26)
  protected 'body' => resource(68, stream)
  protected 'approved' => int 0
  protected 'created_date' => null
  protected 'deleted' => null
  protected 'aUsers' => null
  protected 'aArticlesCategory' => null
  protected 'alreadyInSave' => boolean false
  protected 'alreadyInValidation' => boolean false
  protected 'validationFailures' => 
    array
      empty
  protected '_new' => boolean false
  protected '_deleted' => boolean false
  protected 'modifiedColumns' => 
    array
      empty
  protected 'virtualColumns' => 
    array
      empty
```

but the result I get is

```
object(PropelObjectCollection)[49]

object(Articles)[50]
  protected 'startCopy' => boolean false
  protected 'id' => int 1
  protected 'users_id' => int 1
  protected 'articles_category_id' => int 0
  protected 'images_id' => int 0
  protected 'title' => string 'xxx@gmail.com' (length=22)
  protected 'body' => resource(71, stream)
  protected 'approved' => int 0
  protected 'created_date' => null
  protected 'deleted' => null
  protected 'aUsers' => null
  protected 'aArticlesCategory' => null
  protected 'alreadyInSave' => boolean false
  protected 'alreadyInValidation' => boolean false
  protected 'validationFailures' => 
    array
      empty
  protected '_new' => boolean false
  protected '_deleted' => boolean false
  protected 'modifiedColumns' => 
    array
      empty
  protected 'virtualColumns' => 
    array
      empty
```

The same query worked earlier. I have just started to work with Propel ORM. I don't know what is going wrong. I have already tried regenerating the runtime configuration for php and then generated new model classes. I have integrated Propel with CI. I am still trying to solve this problem and I have no idea what is causing the different output.

Comment: You just have more items in your table. That's all. Any data on what is in your database for the first test and for the second?

Comment: Can you please explain it with examples relating to the above table. You see the first result is obtained correctly with the same query how can it be different without any changes. Still confused.

Comment: But when did you ran these queries? one after the other? One last month, the other today?

Comment: They were working fine till yesterday. Today it didn't work. I think the error is in the model class generation of the propel.

All I did was

    propel-gen . reverse
    propel-gen om
    propel-gen convert-conf


and copied the generated runtime configuration xml and model classes to their respective paths. It should have worked fine with those steps only. But after I ran the query which was supposed to work fine but instead I got incorrect results.

Comment: Can you tell me what is incorrect in the result? Becase when I took a look to the dump you posted, there is **exactly** the same columns. Just the data is different. What is inside your table, could you paste it in your question?

Comment: as you have noticed the different output already, the title for the second output should have been actual row from articles column from articles table. But the propel returned email column from users table, which is not really what I want. and as you can see $articles = ArticlesQuery::create()->find(); should only query the articles table. This is driving me crazy.

Comment: What drive me crazy is that you don't want to post any data from your table Article. Without that, I can't really go further to help you.

Comment: @j0k Sorry for not posting the data. The data is too long and I don't know how to post those data here. While debugging I found that whatever {table}Query object I use for querying always the data of User table is returned. I also viewed the last generated generated query and it turns to be of user table only. which is "SELECT users.ID, users.USERS_ROLES_ID, users.FIRSTNAME, users.LASTNAME, users.EMAIL, users.PASSWORD, users.ONLINE_SCHEDULE, users.NEWSLETTER, users.FB_UID, users.FB_ACCESS_TOKEN, users.CREATED_DATE, users.IP, users.COUNTRY, users.DELETED FROM `users`"

Comment: @j0k Please see the tables structures for the articles and users. You see the data returned is from users table only. http://i76.photobucket.com/albums/j5/alexshr/mysql_desc.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today, I made a really stupid mistake and cost me hours of pain.

Actually in the morning I edited a propel runtime core file "runtime/lib/query/ModelCriteria.php" and replaced the

```
$this->modelPeerName = constant($this->modelName . '::PEER'); 
// with 
$this->modelPeerName = 'UsersPeer'
```

which caused propel to return the data from users table only. @j0k Thanks for the continuous support that kept me with debugging this problem.

I replaced the code earlier because the code generated by propel was not working for the UsersQuery only and was not able to locate constant($this->modelName . '::PEER'); properly.

Hope this won't happen to anyone and I will have habbit of keeping track of changes I made. After finding the actual error, I reverted to the original source and the query began to work as before.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!!! I have been working on this for hours and of course it was something as simple as a class collision. I almost gave up on Propel lol.